# 2016: Moderation Stats

Tags: feature-request

There is a [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340815/2016-a-year-in-moderation) on meta stack overflow that shows the moderation stats on the site for the year. Would it be possible to get something similar to that for this site?

When I inquired about it I was instructed to make a feature request post on the meta where I would like to see the stats.

I figure they would be interesting to see.